# changing IP address between vpn and original ip

Tags: api

i'm executing a python code that uses request module.
because i'm using VPN for some reason, when i make some api calls it automatically uses host's ip address of vpn to make api call. but for the tasks implemented in the script should use my original ip address. And i don't want to disconnect the currently connected vpn.

So my question is that is there any way to use my original ip when using python request module by not disconnecting vpn?

Comment: Did you try looking into split tunnel? If not I would suggest looking into it. That might help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple network interfaces on a machine. You could I guess send some requests over a specific NIC (physical or virtual).